# File is not created when CREATE TABLE in open source delta lake

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, delta-lake

I am using AWS EMR and I am using an open-source delta lake.

In Python, `dataframe.write.format('delta').save()` works fine.

But I want to use it in SQL. I tried to create a delta table in SQL as below.

```
spark.sql('''
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.foo
   (name string)
   USING delta
   LOCATION 's3://<bucket_name>/test/foo'
''');
```

But when I try to INSERT, an error is raised.

```
spark.sql('INSERT INTO test.foo (name) VALUES ("bar")');
```

ERROR: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist`

Tables were created in Glue Metastore, but nothing was created in `s3://<bucket_name>/test/foo` in S3.

Is there any way to create a table in SQL? :)

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you use the wrong name: test.sql_delta. If u use sql and created a sql table it will reference to your physical metastore through the SQL table name you just created.

code should be:

```
spark.sql('INSERT INTO test.foo (name) VALUES ("bar")')
```

SQL version:

```
%SQL
INSERT INTO test.foo (name) VALUES ("bar")
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.